# system() not working in C on cron job

Tags: c, system, cron

The `system()` function does not work when the program is run from a cron job, but it works fine when I manually execute the program.

C Code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

char command[256];

strcpy(command, "mpg123 /home/vlad/MIA/Alarm/test.mp3");
printf("Commnd Executed");
system(command);

return 0;
}
```

Crontab File:

```
*/1 * * * * /home/vlad/MIA/Alarm/test >> /home/vlad/MIA/debug_test.txt
```

Comment: Using C for just a system()? Seriously?

Comment: Not at all, I have a bigger program that has the issue, but I can not even seem to get a simple program to work,that is why I posted that small c program.

Comment: This sounds like a permission or context issue. I doubt you can directly access audio from cron.

Comment: I do not think it is a permission issue, I just gave it 777 and still nothing

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: To see whether your program is being executed at all, try adding this line to your program: `system("echo Job is running >> cron.out");`

Comment: Most of cron debugging can be solved by `echo date >>/tmp/omg.date`

Comment: If an answer solved your problem, you can accept it by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: @KeithThompson is there anyway to export env variables in C like you would in a bash script?

Comment: `man 3 setenv`, `man 3 putenv` (both are POSIX-specific, not standard C, but that's not likely to be an issue).  You can also set environment variables in your crontab; `man 5 crontab` for details.It looks like your original problem was solved; are you planning to accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was a combination, the cron job was not running, I was able to figure that out with the help of Keith Thompson, as well as cron job needed some evnormental variales. The work around I did was to lanuch the C program from a script with the variables needed.

.sh file

```
 #/bin/bash 

##Needed to have cron play an audio file
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
export DISPLAY=:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/vlad/.Xauthority 

#Runs main Alarm check C program. 
/home/vlad/MIA/Alarm/Alarm_Main
```

Answer (score 1):

Cron jobs run with a limited set of environment variables.

To see what the environment looks like, you can create a temporary cron job like this:

```
* * * * * printenv > cron-env
```

The most likely culprit is the `$PATH` variable. It's likely that the `mpg123` command is in a directory that's in your `$PATH` in an interactive shell, but is not in the default `$PATH` provided to cron jobs.

**UPDATE** : I see that the `mpg123` command is provided (on Ubuntu) by the `mpg321` package, which presumably installs it as `/usr/bin/mpg123`. But I don't know what the command does, or how you can tell that it didn't run. Your first step in debugging this should be to try running a simple command so that you can clearly tell whether it ran or not. And just be sure, you are feeding your crontab to the `crontab` command, yes? If so, it should appear in the output of `crontab -l`.

Comment: Turns out you were right, it was the environmental variables, I did more research and I was able to get it all to work but have a script set the variables then launch the program. Here is how I got it to work:    export DISPLAY=:0.0
export XAUTHORITY=/home/vlad/.Xauthority 

#Runs main Alarm check C program. 
/home/vlad/MIA/Alarm/Alarm_Main